# How to extract data from a selected file by pressing a push button in GUI (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab

This is the code of my GUI.

```
function varargout = hyst_gui(varargin)
% HYST_GUI MATLAB code for hyst_gui.fig
%      HYST_GUI, by itself, creates a new HYST_GUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = HYST_GUI returns the handle to a new HYST_GUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      HYST_GUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in HYST_GUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      HYST_GUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new HYST_GUI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before hyst_gui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to hyst_gui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help hyst_gui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 05-Jan-2014 16:19:36

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @hyst_gui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @hyst_gui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before hyst_gui is made visible.
function hyst_gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to hyst_gui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for hyst_gui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes hyst_gui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = hyst_gui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in load.
function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to load (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.*'},'Open Directory');
if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
    return
end
guidata(hObject, handles);

function edit7_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit7 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit7 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit7 as a double

% --- Executes on button press in fit.
function fit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to fit (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton4.
function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton5.
function pushbutton5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton6.
function pushbutton6_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton6 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double


function edit2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit2 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit2 as a double

function edit3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit3 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit3 as a double

function edit4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit4 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit4 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit4 as a double


function edit5_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit5 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit5 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit5 as a double

function edit6_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit6 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit6 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit6 as a double

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function Untitled_1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Untitled_1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

When I press load button, it shows a dialouge box for selecting files. After selecting files how can i extract datapoints written in the file, to plot a graph.

Comment: Could you add the code for your pushbutton's callback to your question?

Comment: Please also explain the type of the file and the structure of the data in the file or even upload an example file ;-)

Comment: I have added the code and the the type of the file to which i want to select may be .txt and .DAT. And the data within the file is in numeric form, it means in X and Y arrays to plot a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback function to load the contents of the is `load_Callback`, I assume:

```
% --- Executes on button press in load.
function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.*'},'Open Directory');
if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
    return
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

[`uigetfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) returns the name of the selected file and its path. It does not read or load it.

First, you need to open the file using `fopen`.

**If the file extension is txt**, you can use functions like `textscan` or `fscanf`.

**If the file extension is dat**, you can use `fread`.

Example for txt file:

```
% --- Executes on button press in load.
function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.*'},'Open Directory');
if isequal(filename, 0) || isequal(pathname, 0)
    return
end
fileID = fopen(strcat(pathname, filename), 'r'); % read-only permission
handles.fileData = textscan(fileID,'%d');
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then, you can access `handles.fileData` from any of your callback functions.

Comment: After reading a text file how can i export it to the base workspace, So that i can use it.

Comment: @user3162506 do you mean MATLAB's workspace, which you can access using command line?

Comment: @user3162506 OK, if I understood you correctly, you can assign the output of the appropriate function to your `handles` structure.

Comment: function load_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to load (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


[filename, pathname] = uigetfile({'*.txt';'*.dat';'*.*'},'Pick a File');
if isequal(filename,0) || isequal(pathname,0)
    return
end

evalin('base',['load(''' filename ''')']);
set(handles.edit7,'string',[filename,pathname]);

handles.B = evalin('base',filename);
assignin('base','B',handles.B);
guidata(hObject, handles);

Comment: This is the updates code of push button.. Now it is able to reading a file and exporting it to the workspace. But i can't access it's data, even with the help of handles...

Comment: @user3162506 I see you accepted my answer. Did you manage to solve your problem? I did not have the time to answer your comment.

Comment: Yeah.. I have solved that problem and thanks for your answer. But now I have another problem...   I have fitted  curve using curvefitting tool. After that i saved data in the base workspace. Now in the workspace it is showing fitmodel1<1*1 cfit>, which contains fitted data points. How can I extract these data points into other variable so that I can use them.

Comment: @user3162506 You can ask a new question about it. I do not think I will be able to help you, I have not used Curve Fitting Toolbox before.

Comment: @user3162506 I added an example, just in case you or anyone else needs it.